# gradle publishing jar into nexus maven repo

Tags: java, gradle, nexus, maven-publish

I am using gradle v3.4 and maven-publish plugin as well as shadow plugin for creating jar files.  I have copied the relevant parts of the build.gradle below as well as the error message.  I do not get an error message when I use **publishing.publications** (but my jar does not get published to the remote nexus repo - I can publish locally).

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) {
            from components.shadow
            groupId 'com.test'
            artifactId 'some-java'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username project.properties['nexusUsername']
                password project.properties['nexusPassword']
            }
            url project.properties['nexus.url.snapshot']
        }
    }
```

**error**

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'some-java'.
> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare in the head the group and the artifact
And use the task `jar`.
After that use:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that alredy.  I am using shadowjar - both jar/shadowjar tasks are before the publishing one.